# Second existence theorem for weak solutions (Evans chapter 6)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The author defines $L_{\gamma}^{-1}$ in the Theorem 4.(the first step in the first picture ) .

> Proof .1. Choose $\mu=\lambda$ as in theorem 3 and define the bilinear form $$B_{\gamma}[u,v]:=B[u,v]+\gamma (u,v),$$
> corresponding to the operator $L_{\gamma}u=Lu+\gamma u$. Then for each $g\in L^2(U)$ there exists a unique function $u\in H_0^1(U)$ solving $$B_{\gamma}[u,v]=g(u,v) 
>  \tag{13}$$
> for all $v\in H_0^1(U)$. Let us write $$u=L_{\gamma}^{-1}g$$ whenever (13) holds…

Though $L_{\gamma}^{-1}$ well-defined, is it a linear operator and how to figure it out?Could someone gives me some details, thank you!

I post the theorem 4 by the first picture below.
[image]

Comment: [Please don't post questions which mostly consist of an image.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/537079) I understand that's not easy to convert the whole thing into MathJax but maybe in the end not all is really needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding! I edit it again.